# Github webhook not posting to Amazon SQS queue due to UnknownOperationException

Tags: github, amazon-sqs, webhooks

I'm trying to configure a Github repository to post to an Amazon SQS queue, via a *[webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#webhooks)* (**not** the pre-configured [SQS Service](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#services)). The queue has full permissions, so anyone can post a message to it - and when I post via `curl`, it works fine.

```
curl -d "Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=curl_testing" https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123/my_queue
```

However, when I use the same queue URL in a webhook and test it, I get a 404, and *UnknownOperationException*.

The default `curl` format is *form-urlencoded*, so I changed the webhook default format (*application/json*) to that - which made no difference. (Interestingly, I also switched `curl` to use *application/json*, and it failed with the same error.)

There aren't a lot of options on the webhook, but I tried them all (with/without a secret token, or SSL certs), with no success.

Is it *possible* to have a webhook post to SQS (with the expected repo information, such as commits, etc)? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

In your curl example you can see that SQS is expecting Action and MessageBody attributes. You can specify them in body of POST request or as the URL parameters. This way it's possible to send notification to SQS queue but you will lost information from webhook which is formatted as JSON.

You can set the action and message body in the webhook Payload URL like this:

```
https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/123/my_queue?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=Webhook_triggered
```

This way whenever the webhook is activated, you will receive SQS message with "Webhook_triggered" body.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, that did work, in the sense that Github successfully posted a message to SQS. But since I was using a repo as the source, there was an unstated assumption that the post would contain repo _information_. All I received in the SQS queue was the "webhook_triggered" message - I have no idea what repo sent the message. So +1 upvote for an interesting solution, but I'm going to revise the question to be more explicit about the goal. (And I tried it _without_ the MessageBody, got a 400).

Comment: Another option would be to include the full repo name in the MessageBody. Then I could query the repo for latest commits, etc. This would be painfully ugly, but _might_ be workable. I'm hoping for other options. :)

Comment: Why don't you use the SqsQueue Service which is there already configured?

Comment: I wondered when someone would ask that. :) @Lubo, it's already in use, sending a message to a Jenkins server that deletes the message immediately.

Comment: @fiatjaf, dealing with software long enough, will do that to you. :) In this case, Github supplies pre-configured services for notifying apps like Jenkins - but the service can only notify _one_ URL, not two different ones. And I have no control over the behavior of the Jenkins server that is at the first URL.

Comment: @JohnC I'm writing a small _webhook redirection_ service that, I imagine, would be suitable for your corner case. It is not ready or anything, but what do you think a service like that would need to be useful?

Comment: @fiatjaf thanks, but the issue is that the webhook isn't properly configured, or at least, does not behave identically to the Jenkins service. Unless you are saying your service can _replicate_ a sent message - then I could send two copies of the message, to the original Jenkins, and to my secondary Jenkins. In either case, this project is OBE - we're switching to Teamcity.

Comment: @JohnC You mean "Order of the British Empire"? Is that your project? Just kidding (but I really don't know what OBE means). I was not thinking about offering my service to you, it is not ready for serious use-cases like yours, I just wanted some advice. Thank you and good luck with the webhooks.